# Tensorflow structure search

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to implement a structure search mechanism, find blocks and wrap them in a block.

I am new to machine learning, at first I started with the `brain.js` This library is quite simple and clear, I realized what was happening from the first time, the library is suitable for simple tasks.

But unfortunately, this library is not functional, earlier I asked how to find blocks: [How to take the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781990/how-to-take-the-data)

I decided to try `tensorflow`, but for understanding this library is difficult, I still do not understand how it learns, because there is input and what the result should be.

Here is an example of how I tried to do a search for a `brain.js`

https://jsfiddle.net/eoy7krzj/

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/BrainJS/brain.js/5797b875/browser.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div>
    <button onclick="train()">train</button><button onclick="Generate.next(); Generate.draw();">generate</button><button onclick="calculate()">calculate</button>
</div>

<canvas id="generate" style="border: 1px solid #000"></canvas>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var trainData = [];

    function randomInteger(min, max) {
        var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
        //rand = Math.round(rand);
        return rand;
    }

    function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';

        var color = '#';

        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }

        return color;
    }


    var Generate   = new function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('generate');
        var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var elem   = {
            input: [],
            output: []
        }

        var size = {
            width: 240,
            height: 140
        }

        canvas.width  = 500;
        canvas.height = 250;

        this.next = function(){
            this.build();

            trainData.push({
                input: elem.input,
                output: elem.output
            });
        }

        this.clear = function(){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }

        this.draw = function(){
            this.clear();

            this.item(elem.input, function(item){
                ctx.strokeStyle = "green";

                ctx.strokeRect(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3]);
            })

            this.item(elem.output, function(item){
                ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";

                ctx.strokeRect(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3]);
            })


        }

        this.item = function(where, call){
            for (var i = 0; i < where.length; i+=4) {
                var input = [
                    where[i],
                    where[i+1],
                    where[i+2],
                    where[i+3],
                ];

                this.denormalize(input);

                call(input)
            }
        }

        this.normalize = function(input){
            input[0] = input[0] / 500;
            input[1] = input[1] / 250;
            input[2] = input[2] / 500;
            input[3] = input[3] / 250;
        }

        this.denormalize = function(input){
            input[0] = input[0] * 500;
            input[1] = input[1] * 250;
            input[2] = input[2] * 500;
            input[3] = input[3] * 250;
        }

        this.empty = function(add){
            var data = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < add; i++) {
                data = data.concat([0,0,0,0]);
            }

            return data;
        }

        this.build = function(){
            var output  = [];
            var input   = [];

            size.width  = randomInteger(100,500);
            size.height = randomInteger(50,250);

            var lines       = 1;//Math.round(size.height / 100);
            var line_size   = 0;
            var line_offset = 0;

            for(var i = 0; i < lines; i++){
                line_size = randomInteger(30,Math.round(size.height / lines));

                var columns        = Math.round(randomInteger(1,3));
                var columns_width  = 0;
                var columns_offset = 0;

                for(var c = 0; c < columns; c++){
                    columns_width = randomInteger(30,Math.round(size.width / columns));

                    var item = [
                        columns_offset + 10,
                        line_offset + 10,
                        columns_width - 20,
                        line_size - 20
                    ];

                    this.normalize(item);

                    input = input.concat(item);

                    columns_offset += columns_width;
                }

                var box = [
                    0,
                    line_offset,
                    columns_offset,
                    line_size
                ]

                this.normalize(box);

                output = output.concat(box);

                line_offset += line_size + 10;
            }

            elem.input  = input.concat(this.empty(5 - Math.round(input.length / 4)));
            elem.output = output.concat(this.empty(2 - Math.round(output.length / 4)));
        }

        this.get = function(){
            return elem.input;
        }


        this.calculate = function(result, stat){
            console.log('brain:',result);

            this.item(result, function(item){
                ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

                ctx.strokeRect(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3]);
            })
        }

        this.train = function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < 1400; i++){
                this.next();
            }
        }
    }

    Generate.train();

    Generate.log = true;

    var net,stat;


    function train(){
        net  = new brain.NeuralNetwork({ hiddenLayers: [4],activation: 'tanh'});
        stat = net.train(trainData,{log: true, iterations: 1250,learningRate: 0.0001,errorThresh:0.0005});

        console.log('stat:',stat)
    }

    function calculate(){
        Generate.calculate(net.run(Generate.get()))
    }


</script>
</html>
```

My goal is to train the network to find the elements and show their sizes.

Procedure: Click to train Click generate Click to calculate

The blue block wraps the green blocks, this should be the result, the red block shows that it has found a neural network.

That's what interests me:

1. Can `tensorflow` find blocks?
2. The data should be in the form of pictures, or numerical data?
3. How do you advise to start?

I would be very grateful if someone would put a small example on how to receive data, in what format and how to train)

**Edit**

I give the size and position of the green blocks, the goal is to find where the green blocks are and their total size, as an example this is shown by the blue block.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Is your goal to find if a small picture is contained in a big picture ?

Comment: Not exactly, I give the size and position of the green blocks, the goal is to find where the green blocks are and their total size, as an example this is shown by the blue block.

Comment: If you give the size and position of the green blocks, you already know them. What is the issue then ? I can't really understand your point. I don't even understand your snippet.

Comment: This is just the simplest example so that a neural network can at least find it. Here for example the task is more difficult: https://jsfiddle.net/rstL4a58/

Answer (score 0):

**Neural Network**

The neural network has a fix input that are the number of green blocks. Lets suppose we are going to find 3 blocks in a picture. The model will have an InputShape of [3, 4] for each block has 4 coordinates `(x, y, w, h)`. The predicted box can be the `min(x), min(y), max(x+w), max(y+h)`. This bounding box will wrap the boxes.
A sample data can be

```
features = [[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 2, 2]]]
labels = [[1, 2, 7, 10]]
```

```js
const random = _ =>  Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
  const generate = _ => {
  xarr = Array.from({length: 3},  _ => random())
  yarr = Array.from({length: 3},  _ => random())
  
  features = xarr.map((x, i) => ([x, yarr[i], x + random(), yarr[i] + random()]))
  labels = features.reduce((acc, f) => ([Math.min(acc[0], f[0]), Math.min(acc[1], f[1]), Math.max(acc[0] + acc[2], f[0] + f[2]),  Math.max(acc[0] + acc[3], f[1] + f[3])]) )
  
  return {features, labels}
  
}

(async () => {
    const model = tf.sequential();
     model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 20, inputShape: [3, 4], activation: 'relu'}));
     model.add(tf.layers.reshape({targetShape: [60]}));
     model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 4, activation: 'relu'}));
 
    model.summary();

 // Prepare the model for training: Specify the loss and the optimizer.
    model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'adam'});

 // Generate some synthetic data for training.
    let x = [];
    let y = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      const data = generate();
      x.push(data.features);
      y.push(data.labels);
    }
    const xs = tf.tensor3d(x);
    const ys = tf.tensor2d(y);
    console.log(xs.shape);
    console.log(ys.shape);

 // Train the model using the data then do inference on a data point the
 // model hasn't seen:
    xs.print()
    ys.print()
    await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 100});
    model.predict(tf.tensor([[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 2, 2]]])).print();
})();
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Convolutionnal filters**

The previous model will generate boxes that wraps up boxes whose coordinates are given to the model. But if we are to find out which position are the matching boxes, one can use a convolution filter.

Let's suppose we want to match the following data `[[1, 2], [5, 6]]` in a tensor. 
This data can be a cropped picture that we want to see if it exists or not in a big picture and if yes, how many times it appears. Using a convolution filter of `[[1, 1], [1, 1]]`, we will have a result of 14 at the top left coordinates `(x, y)` where there is a match. Filtering over this value (14) will return the index of the coordinates of interest.

```js
(async() => {
// tf.setBackend('cpu')
  const arr = Array.from({length: 16}, (_, k) => k+1)

  const x = tf.tensor([...arr, ...arr.reverse()], [8, 4]); // input image 2d
  x.print()

  const filter = tf.ones([2, 2]) // input filter 2d

  const conv = x.reshape([1, ...x.shape, 1]).conv2d(filter.reshape([...filter.shape, 1, 1]), 1, 'same').squeeze()
  
  conv.print() // conv

  const part = tf.tensor([[1, 2], [5, 6]]) // searched tensor

  const mask = conv.equal(part.sum()).asType('bool');
  const coords = await tf.whereAsync(mask);

  coords.print(); // (0, 0) and (4, 0) are the top left coordinates of part of x that matches the part tensor
  
  // how many elements matches
  console.log(coords.shape[0])
  
  // filter coords
  
  const [a, b] = coords.lessEqual(x.shape.map((a, i) => a - part.shape[i] )).split(2, 1);  // because of padding 'same'
  
  const filterMask = a.mul(b)
  const filterCoords = await tf.whereAsync(filterMask);
  filterCoords.print()
  const newCoords = coords.gather(filterCoords.split(2, 1)[0].reshape([2]))
  newCoords.print()
  
   const matchIndexes = await newCoords.unstack().reduce(async (a, c) => {
    const cropped = x.slice(await c.data(), part.shape)
    const sameElements = (await tf.whereAsync(cropped.equal(part).asType('bool')))
    if(tf.util.sizeFromShape(part.shape) * 2 === (await sameElements.data()).length) {
      a.push(await c.data())
    }
    return a
  }, [])
  console.log('matching index', matchIndexes) // only [0, 0]
})()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

To be more thorough, the convolutional filters is not enough to tell if there is a match. Actually a part of the tensor with the following values `[[5, 6], [2, 1]]` will also output 14. To make sure of outputting only the correct index, one can slice the input tensor at the given coordinates and check values bitwise if possible when the tensor processed are not big or just randomly some few elements.

Comment: Thank you very much) Your example works, but there is one thing that I cannot figure out how to do. https://jsfiddle.net/Lk2u3b51/ Now I have a different number of blocks, I tried to change (inputShape), but it’s not how I can’t set the desired number.

Comment: @user2783211 If you change the number of blocks, the inputShape will be: `inputShape: [numberBlocks, 4]`. But you would also needs to change `xs` and `ys` to match the new shape you set in the `inputShape`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a3k94v7z/ I made 4 blocks, changed (inputShape) also to 4, but an error appears (Error: Total size of new array must be unchanged)

Comment: @user2783211 If you use https://stackblitz.com for your snippet, I can fix it for you